# Weird behavior of Button placing in Relative layout with AppCompatTheme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

Look at code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wi_fi_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#feeca0"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="#b5a24f" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/wifi_progressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This type of element placing, work before updating UI theme to AppCompat. After updating, all buttons overlap elements in all case, even their must be upper (According to xml code)

[image]

This is my ActivityThem style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/AppTheme.ButtonsTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/SwitcherStyle</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, there are textAppearance overriding only. Parent components of Button(Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button) don't have any special attributes(i hope to find something like in web ccs - z-index). 
I solve this problem: just wrap button with frame layout, and my behavior returns(Progress bar draws on Buttons view).

**So,does any body know this is bug or feature of Button in AppCompat?**

*P.S: screenshot from AS, but behavior the same on device also.*

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion about Z index is correct. Android 5 introduced shadows and elevation. `Button` has default elevation `2dp` which makes it render above other widgets with smaller elevation (in the same layout), such as `ProgressBar` with no elevation.

Elevation is ignored on devices running Android 4 and older. Your progress bar would draw over the button.

Quickest and dirtiest fix would be to assign `android:elevation="10dp"` to the progress bar. It won't draw any shadows because it doesn't have any background. But it will have greater elevation than a button in pressed state.